# Rails Associations appearing 'nil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm new to Rails and Web Dev and really stumped.  I have two models `user` and`property`.  You cannot create a property unless you are a user (logged in).  I'm having problems with associations as I have in the `user` model `has_many properties` and `belongs_to user` in `property` model.  When a property is created, when I check the console, it has the correct `user_id`.

Problem:  When I check the user in the console, I get message `property_id: nil`.  Can someone explain what code I need in order for the `property_id` to populate for the `user`?   (I figure it probably has something to do with the user being created before the property but I thought the associations would automatically take care of this)

I'm using `devise` in case that is a factor and I added `:property_id` to the permitted parameters method.

Relevant code is below:

Models:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
validates :user_id, presence: true 
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

2)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_many :properties

end
```

Controllers:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]


def index
    @properties = Property.all
end

def new 
    @property = current_user.properties.new
end

def create
    @property = current_user.properties.new(property_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: "Property was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json 
      end
    end
end

def update      
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.update(property_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: "You've successfully updated your property listing!" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

end
```

2)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!
load_and_authorize_resource

def index
    @users = User.all
end

end
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email,       :password, :password_confirmation, :property_id) }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong, the property_id will not store in User table.
You have one to many relationship. What happens when a single user has 3 properties then you will store 3 property_id in that single user record.
No, beside that you are doing right in your code, Property table will have user_id and you will get all properties of a particular User by doing this in your controller.

```
@user = User.find(:user_id)
@properties = @user.properties
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Makes sense after going over it again.  I'm learning slowly but surely. ;)